# N-th prime number

Tags: c++

Input
First line contains a positive integer k. Then k positive integers follow (one in each line). The numbers don't exceed 15000.
Output
For each number n output the n-th by order prime number. Each number should be in its line.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>

long long getNthPrime(int n)
{
    long long size{};

    if(n<11)
    {
        size=n*n;
    }
    else{
        size=n*log(n)*log(n);
    }

    std::vector<int>is_prime(size+1, 1);
    is_prime[0]=is_prime[1]=0;
    is_prime[2]=1;
    int count=1;
    if(n==1)
    {
        return 2;
    }
    for(long long i=3; i<=size; i+=2)
    {
        if(is_prime[i]==1)
        {
            count++;
            if(count==n)
            {
                return i;
            }
            for(long long j=i*i; j<=size; j+=i)
            {
                is_prime[j]=0;
            }
        }

    }

}

int main() {

    int n, k;
    std::cin>>k;
    std::vector<int>arr;

    for(int i=0; i<k; i++)
    {
        std::cin>>n;
        arr.push_back(n);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<k; i++)
    {
        std::cout<<getNthPrime(arr[i])<<std::endl;
    }


}
```

It gives "time limit" error message. I checked several times to see if there is anything wrong withing but I couldn't find. Any hints would be highly appreciated

Comment: Hint: what happens when `k` is big enough?

Comment: Q: What is a "time limit" error message?  I don't understand.  Q: Have you tried your program with the first few primes (say, larger than "11', up to 23) by stepping through a line at a time under the debugger?  Q: Where do you get your algorithm?  Have you considered trying a different one?

Comment: I suspect the "time limit" is the response he gets from a challenge coding site like HackerRank or Codechef or the like. If this code is working but runs out of time, it should be posted on [**Code Review Stack Exchange**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead of here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because review of working code belongs on [**Code Review Stack Exchange**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: thanks for the comments, now I understand it much better

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For each number n, you are generating a whole sequence of primes up to n. This is a colossal waste of time.

FYI, the 15000th prime is 163841 (starting with 2 being 1st); I suggest you make a [sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) of 163841 elements, this will give you all 15000 primes you need to answer the queries, all at once; then collect them into an array of 15000 elements; only then start iterating through the input numbers and looking them up, which should be superfast (as it's just plain array lookup).

Comment: thanks for the kind and good response. Yes I know that the 15000th prime is 163841, but what about if we didn't know

Comment: Why wouldn't you know? Prime tables have been published for ages. You could have found this information already in [1776](https://primes.utm.edu/glossary/page.php?sort=TablesOfPrimes); it's silly to assume we can't do that in 2018. But, you could also look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Approximations_for_the_nth_prime_number) for an upper bound on n-th prime (`n * (ln n + ln ln n)`), which is ~178188.2 for n=15000 (so your array is a bit larger, but hardly a dealbreaker)